# Makefile target pattern contains no '%'

Tags: makefile, ubuntu-13.10

This is my makefie

```
java -cp .:jsoup-1.8.1.jar:mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar:. Client.java
```

and when I run it I'm getting

```
makefile:1: *** target pattern contains no '%'. Stop.
```

How to manage that. I'm running it on Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Another thing to check for this error is if there is a messed up file named .depend in the current directory.

Comment: You need to add a backslash to every troublesome character: `java -cp .\:js....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a valid Makefile; you need to wrap the command in a rule instead, e.g.

```
all:
    java -cp .:jsoup-1.8.1.jar:mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar:. Client.java
```

You should also add dependencies and write the Makefile properly though, so that it will only rebuild if `Client.java` changes, e.g.

```
all: Client.java
    java -cp .:jsoup-1.8.1.jar:mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar:. Client.java
```

Side note though; that won't compile your Java file, just try and run it (probably unsuccessfully). You should try and write a Makefile that will take each Java file and compile it into its own class file, then link into a Jar. An example can be found here: http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/javamakefiles.html